# Using a Variable to refer to an Image IBOutlet and changing the Image

Tags: ios, image, swift, variables, iboutlet

thanks for taking the time to read this.

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

var sliderValue:Int = 0
var imageName: String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var im1: WKInterfaceImage!
@IBOutlet weak var im2: WKInterfaceImage!


@IBAction func sliderAction(value: Float) {

    sliderValue = Int(value)
    imageName = "im\(sliderValue)"   
}


@IBAction func button() {
imageName.setImageNamed(sliderValue)
}
```

The problem: I want to use the variable     imageName and use it as the name of the IBOutlet (so it imageName is either im1 or im2). So basically this is what i want (but doesnt work obviously):

```
imageName.setImageNamed(sliderValue)
```

How to make that possible?

Best regards and many thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Put your images into an array after they are initialized but before they are accessed.

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
  // ...
  var images : [WKInterfaceImage] = []

  func viewDidLoad () {
    super.viewDidLoad
    images = [im1, im2]
  }    
}
```

Now you can access them based on the slider values, used as an index into the `images` array.

Or better, if you can limit the *first* access to `images` to after `im1` and `im2` are bound:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
  // ...
  lazy var images : [WKInterfaceImage] = [im1, im2]
  // ...
}
```

With either of the above you can define the buttons, slider action, or computed properties as needed for you particular coding style/needs.